# Is it possible to return two lists from a function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

I am new to python programming and need your help for the following:

I want to return two lists from a function in python. How can i do that. And how to read them in the main program. Examples and illustrations would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return [1,2], [2,3]` returns a tuple of the two lists, the same as `return ([1,2], [2,3])`

Comment: Yes, this is called ***tuple unpacking***. The caller needs to unpack and handle the result, that's all.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can return a tuple of lists, an use sequence unpacking to assign them to two different names when calling the function:

```
def f():
    return [1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]

list1, list2 = f()
```

Answer (score 21):

You can return as many value as you want by separating the values by commas:

```
def return_values():
    # your code
    return value1, value2
```

You can even wrap them in parenthesis as follows:

```
return (value1, value2)
```

In order to call the function you can use one of the following alternatives:

```
value1, value2 = return_values() #in the case where you return 2 values

values= return_values() # in the case values will contain a tuple
```