# ValueError while trying to get two lists from single function

Tags: python-3.x

Have a function which returns two lists of dicts like [{'a':'b'}, {'a':'c'}, {'a':'d'}]. Calling this function in main:

```
def main ():
    a_list, b_list = filter_(firstjson, secondjson)
```

And getting:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
What is the right way to get two lists from single function?

Comment: Sorry. This question already has an answer. I need tuple unpacking )) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690333/is-it-possible-to-return-two-lists-from-a-function-in-python

Comment: What *exactly* does `filter_` return? Can you show the function?

Comment: @MrFuppes, I'm filtering data with this function and need to have two lists with different type of data (topics of articles). Dicts are of this kind:  {'link': 'https://vmo24.ru/news/v_kolomne_ssora_mezhdu_dvumya_muzhchinami_pererosla_v_ponozhovshchinu', 'art_id': 280, 'marker': ''}. I've already found how to manage such situation. The function ends with: `return (a_list, b_list)`...

Comment: It's fine if this has already been solved, but in the future you have to include the code for `filter_`. Otherwise, without seeing it's return statements, no one would be able to help.